# Why does C# Not see the variable in another Script when Using GetComponent? C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

So I have a CharacterController Class that just deals with User inputs and If the player is hit by a bullet and reduces the Health of that Character. I need to use this Health Value in another Script so Have used the following code to try this however I get a CS01061 as it says it cannot find the Health variable.

Character Controller Class Variables:

```
public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public float MovementSpeed = 2;
    public float JumpForce = 5;
    public float Health = 100f;
    public float height = 10;
    public static GameObject LocalPlayerInstance;
```

Here is the code for the PlayerManager Class that needs Health from above:

```
//Gloabl Variables
public GameObject ActualPlayer;
public CharacterController Controller;
public float Health;
public void Awake()
        {
            ActualPlayer = GameObject.Find("Player");
            Controller = ActualPlayer.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
            Health = Controller.Health;
            ......
```

Player is a prefab that is a GameObject that has been initialised by Photon and has the CharacterController script as a component. Why can't unity see that the script has a health variable?

Comment: Select the `Controller` variable, right click, then choose "Go to definition." Now select the type to the left of the symbol and "Go to definition" again. Does this navigate to the class you have defined? Or does it go somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure it is looking for the correct type and not maybe one with the same name but from a different namespace?

Unity itself already has a built-in type named [`CharacterController`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html) in the namespace `UnityEngine` so most probably your second script is using that type since on the top you will have a

```
using UnityEngine;
```

Make sure you are referencing the correct one in your script.

You could e.g. put yours into a specific namespace like

```
namespace MyStuff
{
    public class CharacterController : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

and then in your other script explicitly use

```
public MyStuff.CharacterController Controller;
```

and

```
Controller = ActualPlayer.GetComponent<MyStuff.CharacterController>();
Health = Controller.Health;
```

---

Besides that remember that `float` is a **value** type, not a **reference**, so most probably you storing that value in a field in your second script is not what you want to do ;)

rather always simply access the `Controller.Health` instead.

Comment: The context is that the health from the CharacterController Class needs to be known by a UI script so it can show the right health for the player, this happens in the update() Function so I don't think it matters if its by value or reference as long as it gives the same number to the UI

My new issue is that PlayerManager is in another folder to where the rest of the scripts are and the namespace "brum" (the namespace I put CharacterController in) cannot be found in that folder.

Comment: Sounds like you should look into [Assembly Definitions and References](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompilationAssemblyDefinitionFiles.html)

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot